# implode to fix update sql

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I have this function

```
function updateDbRecord($db, $table, $carry, $carryUrl) {   
    mysql_select_db($db) or die("Could not select database. " . mysql_error());
    $resultInsert = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table . " WHERE Field NOT IN ('id')");
    $fieldnames=array();
      if (mysql_num_rows($resultInsert) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultInsert)) {
            $fieldnames[] = $row['Field'];
            $arr = array_intersect_key( $_POST, array_flip($fieldnames) ); #check if value is null otherwise do not INSERT
        }
      }

      $set = "";
      foreach($arr as $key => $v) {
        $val = is_numeric($v) ? $v : "'" . $v . "'";

        $set .= $key . '=' . $val . ', ';
      }
      $sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE id='%s'", $table, $set, $_POST['id']);
      mysql_query($sql);
      if ($carry == 'yes') {
        redirect($carryUrl.'?id='.$_REQUEST['id']);
      } else { echo "Done!"; }
      echo $sql;

}
```

It outputs for example: UPDATE projects SET project_name='123', project_bold='123', project_content='123', WHERE id='12'

The last comma before where is preventing it from working. Is there a way of avoiding this? Im aware of the function implode, however I am not sure how to employ it in this situation.

Comment: Please fix the SQL injection vulnerabilities, and consider switching to either the MySqli or PDO extensions to access your database (the MySql extension is obselete).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
$sql = substr($sql,'',-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
```

Either that or instead of appending to a string, append to an array and use `implode`.

Comment: I have been trying to implement this solution to no avail. Could you please give me an example within this context? For a previous function of insert i did it this way:    $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ("%s")', $table, 
   implode(', ', array_map('mysql_escape_string', array_keys($values))), implode('", "',array_map('mysql_escape_string', $values))); 
   mysql_query($sql);

Comment: @Alex why not just use something like `PDO`?

Comment: Haven't learned it yet, and within the rhelm of this project I dont have time :( But when i do i will certainty read material on it!

Comment: @Alex honestly I think it will take you about 5 minutes of trying before you learn, and it will save you so much time afterwards!  It is much simpler than you seem to think.

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateDbRecord($db, $table, $carry, $carryUrl) {   
    mysql_select_db($db) or die("Could not select database. " . mysql_error());
    $resultInsert = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table . " WHERE Field NOT IN ('id')");
    $fieldnames=array();
      if (mysql_num_rows($resultInsert) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultInsert)) {
            $fieldnames[] = $row['Field'];
            $array = array_intersect_key( $_POST, array_flip($fieldnames) ); #check if value is null otherwise do not INSERT
        }
      }
      foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

                $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value); // this is dedicated to @Jon
                $value = "'$value'";
                $updates[] = "$key = $value";
            }
      $implodeArray = implode(', ', $updates);
      $sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE id='%s'", $table, $implodeArray, $_POST['id']);
      mysql_query($sql);
```